# The remote name could not be resolved: 'localhost'

Tags: .net, localhost, webrequest, webexception

How can the application not be able to lookup localhost?

```
The remote name could not be resolved: 'localhost'; 

StackTrace;    
      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

the application works a couple of hours and then stops.

**Edit** I import the service as a webreference and call it using the generated Reference.vb file.

Comment: Maybe you should also show, how you call the WebService. It's too hard to guess what you're doing/trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odd things like this can happen when your app is leaking operating system resources.  Like handles or kernel memory pool.  Stuff stops working when it exceeds the process quota, error messages aren't always great.

Run Taskmgr.exe, Process tab, View + Select Columns.  Tick at least Handles and Threads.

Comment: Correct. I'm tracking down the memory leak with the help of the following articles: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2006/05/03/588974.aspx and http://www.componentfactory.com/blog/2006/07/find-net-memory-leaks/